# Problemas para instalar "IBM IAccess Client Solutions en Linux (Xubunto)

Tags: linux

Está es fácil para cualquiera que conozca Linux. Tengo que instalar ese software  **IBM IAccess Client Solutions** en *Linux (Xubunto)*. Ya lo descargué en un archivo tipo **.rpm**. Según una documento de IBM solo tengo que escribir `rpm -i <filename>.rpm`.
Pero eso no funciona, me arroja el siguiente error:

> ```
> rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
> rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
> error: Failed dependencies:
> ```

Debe ser algo realmente sencillo, el asunto es que no sé nada de Linux. Ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como indica el mensaje, deberías utilizar alien.

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Y tras finalizar, instala tu fichero RPM directamente:

```
sudo alien -i <filename>.rpm
```

Documentación:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto

Comment: Hola. Gracias por tu ayuda. Aún  sigo con problemas. Hice lo que me indicaste: instale alien y luego, usando alien, trato de instalar el IBM iaccess, pero al final solo conseguí convertir mi paquete a un formato debian bm-iaccess_1.1.0.13-2_amd64.deb generated. Lo siento, no se nada deLinux

Comment: Puedes volver a repetir el proceso (sudo alien -i <filename>.rpm)? O por el contrario, para tu paquete .deb, puedes ejecutar:
 sudo dpkg -i <filename>.deb

Comment: Hola Zito_MA, al fin logré instalar el programa, muchas gracias x tu ayuda.